# No mouseup after losing hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/rpfHw/

We have an `input` and class `active`, which is added on `mousedown` and removed on `mouseup`.

It works good when mouse cursor is placed over input.

The problem is, `mouseup` doesn't work after you click on `input`, hold and remove cursor from it - class `active` is not removed.

Can it be fixed?

Comment: This seems to be working fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: probably not, the definition of a click event is mousedown and mouseup in the same element. If you wanted to be tricky you would bind the mouse down and up functions to the parent of the input or the document and then check to see if the mouse down started in the input.

Comment: The "target" of the `mouseup` is whatever element the mouse is on top of when you let go.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `mouseup` was not fired on the input, but outside it. You can use a generic event handler on the `document` object for that:

```
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    $('input.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rpfHw/1/

Comment: large pages make huge number of repeats for just one  `$(document).mouseup()`

Comment: on my page there are ~60 calls for a single `$(document).mouseup()`

Comment: @Steve You don't need to bind the event to `document`, bind it to the closest parent of your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I will propose a CSS solution. You can achive the same effect with this rules:

```
input:active{
    outline: 10px solid #000;
}
```

(IE8+)

http://jsfiddle.net/rpfHw/6/

Comment: true, but I need this to style siblings of input

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to listen for the events focusin and focusout. The mouseevents will not fire if you select the input with the keyboard or leave them with the keyboard.

You can do it like this:

```
$('input').on('focusin focusout', function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active', event.type==='focusin');
});
```

The problem you are describing will still occure, because the element will still have the focus if you mousedown inside and drag the mouse outside, but I guess that is ok because the input will still have its focus.

If you want to handle it completely with mouse events and also want to accout for this problem of dragging the mouse outside, than you will have to implement it with mouse events on the dom object and then check for the proper elements inside the handler.

Comment: focus is not an `active` state, not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Is working fine for me, please check the following code:

$('input').bind('click mouseup mousedown', function(event) {
    // some code for a click event

```
if (event.type == 'mousedown'){
    console.log('mousedown');    
    $(this).addClass('active');
    }


if (event.type == 'mouseup'){
    console.log('mouseup');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
}

//console.log(event.type);
```

});
http://jsfiddle.net/rpfHw/3/

Best

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried many ways to fix this.

Better result comes with a replacement of `mouseup` with `mouseout`.

Since we're using mouse, it just removes class when not hovered.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue recently. I fixed this by adding a **mouseleave** event to the target element.